# Variable not defined in Jasmine test case although its in scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, scope, jasmine

I want to test a controller where it listens on an event to do some stuff. The event handler is dependent on a **global** variable called `Main`. I'm trying to unit test the event listener by mocking all dependencies but **Karma** throws error :

`ReferenceError: Main is not defined`

**Angular Code :**

```
App.controller('AppController', ['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
        Main.initComponents(); // init core components
    });
}]);
```

**Spec file :**

```
describe("App", function () {
    var scope, AppController, Main;
    describe("Login", function () {
        beforeEach(module("App"));
        beforeEach(inject(['$rootScope', '$controller', function($rootScope, $controller){
            scope = $rootScope.$new();
            Main = jasmine.createSpyObj("Main",["initComponents"]);
            AppController = $controller('AppController', {$scope : scope});
        }]));
        it("should call initComponents() on Main module on $viewContentLoaded event", inject(['$rootScope', function ($rootScope) {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('$viewContentLoaded');
            expect(Main.initComponents).toHaveBeenCalled();
        }]));
    });
});
```

**karma.conf.js :**

```
module.exports = function(config){
    config.set({

        basePath : './',

        files : [
            'app/bower_components/angular/angular.js',
            'app/bower_components/oclazyload/dist/oclazyLoad.min.js',
            'app/bower_components/angular-ui-router/release/angular-ui-router.min.js',
            'app/bower_components/angular-mocks/angular-mocks.js',
            'app/**/app.js',
            'app/**/controllers.js',
            'app/**/services.js',
            'app/**/directives.js',
            'app/**/filters.js',
            'app/**/routes.js',
            'app/**/specs.js'
        ],

        autoWatch : true,

        frameworks: ['jasmine'],

        browsers : ['Chrome'],

        plugins : [
            'karma-chrome-launcher',
            'karma-firefox-launcher',
            'karma-jasmine',
            'karma-junit-reporter'
        ],

        junitReporter : {
            outputFile: 'test_out/unit.xml',
            suite: 'unit'
        }

    });
};
```

What is the problem? Thanks for help.

Comment: As stated in the error, there should be a `Main` variable of type object in your main JS file where your Angular code is present. You can stub/mock  only existing objects. You cannot create a new Spy object in your Spec and expect it to be known in your main JS.

Comment: @Arkantos, why javascript won't use the `Main` thats in scope? the main is definded before initiation of the controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a variable visibility issue because of the scope in which these variables are defined.

For your `$viewContentLoaded` handler to work properly it needs a `Main` object which is **NOT** defined in the current scope or in any of it's parent scopes in the scope chain. The `Main` mock object that you created using `createSpyObj` is in the scope of your `App` test suite defined using `describe()`. If you look at your code,

```
describe("App", function () {
    var scope, AppController, Main; 
    /* remaining code */
}
```

> As you can see above, `Main` is a local variable defined in the
>   `describe()` method, so it's available only within that function or to
>   any child functions defined inside this function.

Any function outside of `describe()` like your event handler ($on) in Main JS will not know of its existence. That is the reason you get an error when that handler is invoked.

You can resolve this by initializing `Main` properly in 2 ways.

1. You can do this before your event handler is registered either before creating your Angular Module (or) inside the controller.
2. You can make `Main` an Angular service in the same module, inject it into
   your controller like below.

**Main JS**

```
 App.service('Main', function(){

 });

 App.controller('AppController', ['$scope', 'Main', function($scope, Main){
        $scope.$on('$viewContentLoaded', function() {
            Main.initComponents(); // init core components
        });
 }]);
```